# Connecting iOS to wireless device

Tags: ios, objective-c, tcp

I'm developing wireless gadgets to be controlled from different iOS Apps and I'm stuck with the connection and TCP messages part. Can anyone point me in what direction should I go?

To start, the first device is like a Belkin WeMo device. I've already added a network scanner with simple pings, but I don't fully understand the mechanism.

Comment: follow this [Belkin WeMo sdk document page](http://developers.belkin.com/wemo/sdk)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd already checked that document page. Belkin provides all the .h documents but the source code is packed inside a .a file so I can't see anything about the implementation.